# Google Sheets Script to copy groups of rows and paste to a separate tab in the sheet. It works but it's duplicating the groups?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm creating a spreadsheet that operates as a mental health journal that users can fill out throughout the week, which then will automatically send a PDF of that week's entries to their therapist.

I'm having it loop through to check each entry and whether that date has been sent or not to find the entries to copy over, and then copy them to the relevant tab, then mark that entry with a 'yes' to verify that it has been sent.

The issue is that it's duplicating the entries when it copies them over, so there are like 3 copies of the same data even though it only needs it once. I suspect it's something to do with the variables but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to fix it.

I hope this makes sense lol, I'm finding this difficult to explain.

This is what I currently have for the code. It's pasting the correct information to the correct tab, but it's pasting it multiple times instead of just once.

```
function sendReport() {
  ss.getSheetByName("Today").hideSheet();
  ss.getSheetByName("Enjoyable Activities Inventory").hideSheet();
  ss.getSheetByName("Use Guide").hideSheet();
  ss.getSheetByName("Skills List").hideSheet();



  var logsheet = ss.getSheetByName(LOG);
  //var startRow = 5;
  var numRows = logsheet.getLastRow();
  //var logspot = logsheet.getRange(loglastrow + 4, 1, journaldata.length, journaldata[0].length).setValues(journaldata);
  
  var dataRange = logsheet.getRange(5, 1, numRows, logsheet.getLastColumn());
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  for (i in data){
      var info ={
        date : data[i][1],
        emailSent : data[i][44],
      }
      if(info.date instanceof Date){
        if(info.emailSent !== 'yes'){

          var tz = Session.getTimeZone();
          fdate = Utilities.formatDate(info.date, tz, "MM/dd/yyyy");
          var x = 5;
          const row = +i + +x;
          Logger.log(info.emailSent);
          Logger.log("unsent");
          logsheet.getRange(row,45).setValue('yes');
 
          var name = Session.getActiveUser().getUsername();
          var subject = name +" DBT Card Report | "+fdate;
          var message = "test";

          var rows = 33;
          var end = +row + +rows;
          //var z = 5;
          //var roww = +row - +z;
          var copyrange = logsheet.getRange(row,1,end,44);
          var copydata = copyrange.getValues();

          //why is it pasting them multiple times???

          var emailsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Email");

          var pastelastrow = emailsheet.getLastRow();
          var pastespot = emailsheet.getRange(pastelastrow + 4, 1, copydata.length, copydata[0].length).setValues(copydata);
          copyrange.copyTo(pastespot);



          //GmailApp.sendEmail(rejectionEmail,user.subject,'',{htmlBody: htmlrejectionMessage});
          //Logger.log("email sent");
        }
      }

  }
```

Comment: Use the debugger to figure out what going wrong

Comment: Debugger doesn't return anything. No breakpoints

Comment: This `var dataRange = logsheet.getRange(5, 1, numRows, logsheet.getLastColumn());` should be `var dataRange = logsheet.getRange(5, 1, logsheet.getLastRow() - 4, logsheet.getLastColumn());`

Comment: This `Session.getTimeZone()` should be `Session.getScriptTimeZone()` Session doesn't have a method called getTimeZone()

Comment: Your not getting  breakpoints because the code has errors in it.

Answer (score 0):

This is all I could figure out from you code:

```
function sendReport() {
  ss.getSheetByName("Today").hideSheet();
  ss.getSheetByName("Enjoyable Activities Inventory").hideSheet();
  ss.getSheetByName("Use Guide").hideSheet();
  ss.getSheetByName("Skills List").hideSheet();
  var logsheet = ss.getSheetByName(LOG);
  var data = logsheet.getRange(5, 1, logsheet.getLastRow() - 4, logsheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  data.forEach((r, i) => {
    let info = { date: r[1], emailSent: r[44] };
    if (info.emailSent !== 'yes') {
      var tz = Session.getTimeZone();
      fdate = Utilities.formatDate(info.date, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy");
      var x = 5;
      logsheet.getRange(i + 5, 45).setValue('yes');
      //I can't tell what you are trying to do after this
    }
  });
}
```